# Show a D3 SVG Within a Tooltip

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tooltip

I have the following jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nxC7d/1/

When you click on the span element, its text is parsed as `YAML`, and the resulting data is used to create a pie chart via `D3`. My issue is that the pie chart `svg` element is currently just inserted into the body, and I would like it to appear in a tooltip when the `span` is clicked.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the tooltip a floating `div` (i.e. position `fixed`) and append the SVG to that. Also, keep a reference to the SVG so that you can reuse it and don't create a new one on each click.

Complete example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nxC7d/3/). This can obviously be made fancier, but it should get you started.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for steering me in the right direction. This is what I came up with: http://jsfiddle.net/nxC7d/4/